# MySQL column privilege overrides global privilege despite no conflict

Tags: mysql

I have two roles **'r_nddb_read'** and **'r_nddb_verify'**

**'r_nddb_read'** is granted 'SELECT' privileges at the schema level:

[image]

**'r_nddb_verify'** is granted 'UPDATE' privileges at the column level in the 'operating_data' table:
[image]

I have a user **'TestUserVerify'**, that has both **'r_nddb_read'** and **'r_nddb_verify'** roles assigned AND active:
[image]

The **'TestVerifyUser'** can, as expected, SELECT against the 'operating_data table' (because of the global schema 'SELECT' privilege granted via the 'r_nddb_read' role):
[image]

*However*, when I try to use an 'UPDATE' command on the same table, affecting the 'verified' column, with the same WHERE clause used in the select I get the following error:
[image]

despite the fact that the user demonstrability can 'SELECT' the cycle_id column per the previous query.

What I assume is happening is that the 'column' privilege is taking precedence over the schema level privilege.  This is not what I expected, since I thought the privileges were mainly additive.

I think the fix for this is to grant column level 'SELECT' permissions to my **'r_nddb_verify'** role, but that seems superfluous with the schema permissions so I wanted to make sure I'm not doing something wrong/inappropriate.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: I have been using MySQL for 20 years, but I've never used column-level privileges. It's not worth the headache. I suggest you use VIEWs for column-level access control.

Comment: @BillKarwin They do seem... finicky.  Unfortunately I don't think that will work for our particular desired use case.  We want this 'verify' role to ONLY be able to change the 'verified' column in the table, not make any changes to other columns in the table.  So even a view with limited columns and a table level UPDATE privilege would still allow the 'verify' role to make updates to columns they shouldn't be able to touch.  I do generally try to use views instead of the column level privileges though :/